# svg - Filter background colours apply to path

Tags: html, css, svg, svg-filters

I'm trying to replicate what I'm already doing in CSS for a class for an SVG element.

The fill property inherits the currentColour of the parent, let's say red for arguments sake.

I then apply a few linear gradients at different opacity values, and apply different background blend modes to each gradient.

This works perfectly for the css class.

Now what I've tried so far for the SVG is this:

```html
<svg class="shape" width="100%" height="100vh" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1440 800" xmlns:pathdata="http://www.codrops.com/">

    <!-- background-image: 
      linear-gradient(-180deg,  rgba(black,0.69) 0%,  rgba(black,0.69) 100%),
      linear-gradient(-180deg,  rgba(black,0.100) 0%,  rgba(black,0.100) 100%),
      linear-gradient(-180deg,  rgba(black,0.49) 0%,  rgba(black,0.49) 100%);
    background-blend-mode: luminosity, lighten, saturation; -->

    <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%">
            <feFlood x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.69" result="lumiFill"/>
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="lumiFill" mode="luminosity" result="lumiBlend"/>
            <feFlood x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.1" result="lightenFill"/>
            <feBlend in="lumiBlend" in2="lightenFill" mode="lighten" result="lightenBlend"/>
            <feFlood x="0" y="0" width="100%" height="100%" flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.49" result="saturationFill"/>
            <feBlend in="lightenBlend" in2="saturationFill" mode="saturation" result="saturationBlend"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect width="300" height="100" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```

This does appear to change the colour, but I beleive it's stopping at the first flood as I can pull out the other two after it and it seems to work fine.

Can anyone suggest what I might be doing wrong?

Answer (score 1):

This is working as written. If you tweak the flood dimensions so they're offset, you can see that each primitive is doing what you specified.

What effect are you trying to accomplish? (Complete code example - not just a CSS fragment)

```html
<svg class="shape" width="100%" height="100vh" preserveAspectRatio="none" viewBox="0 0 1440 800" xmlns:pathdata="http://www.codrops.com/">

    <!-- background-image: 
      linear-gradient(-180deg,  rgba(black,0.69) 0%,  rgba(black,0.69) 100%),
      linear-gradient(-180deg,  rgba(black,0.100) 0%,  rgba(black,0.100) 100%),
      linear-gradient(-180deg,  rgba(black,0.49) 0%,  rgba(black,0.49) 100%);
    background-blend-mode: luminosity, lighten, saturation; -->

    <defs>
        <filter id="f1" x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="100%" primitiveUnits="objectBoundingBox">
            <feFlood x="0%" y="0%" width="60%" height="100%" flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.69" result="lumiFill"/>
            <feBlend in="SourceGraphic" in2="lumiFill" mode="luminosity" result="lumiBlend"/>
            <feFlood x="40%" y="0%" width="60%" height="100%" flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.1" result="lightenFill"/>
            <feBlend in="lumiBlend" in2="lightenFill" mode="lighten" result="lightenBlend"/>
            <feFlood x="0%" y="0%" width="100%" height="50%" flood-color="black" flood-opacity="0.49" result="saturationFill"/>
            <feBlend in="lightenBlend" in2="saturationFill" mode="saturation" result="saturationBlend"/>
        </filter>
    </defs>
    <rect x="50px" y="50px" width="300px" height="100px" fill="red" filter="url(#f1)" />
</svg>
```

Comment: The reason why I thought it wasn't working is the fact that the fe blend modes don't support the same blend modes as css, so it was basically applying the default blend mode.

Comment: I think Chrome supports the new blend modes (SVG 2) - will have to test - but Safari definitely doesn't